# big cpu load on vmware server / linux

Tags: vmware-server

I currently using a server 2.x hosting 4 virtual machines on a linux system

Today, on my physical server, I saw an enormous load average:

this is the "top" of the server, illustrating my 4 virtual guests.

```
top - 11:02:02 up 194 days, 23:09, 5 users, load average: 18.78, 12.05, 13.55
Tasks: 113 total, 4 running, 109 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu0 : 71.6%us, 19.0%sy, 0.0%ni, 8.8%id, 0.0%wa, 0.3%hi, 0.3%si, 0.0%st
Cpu1 : 74.3%us, 10.4%sy, 0.0%ni, 15.3%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
Cpu2 : 72.5%us, 17.6%sy, 0.0%ni, 9.8%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
Cpu3 : 79.5%us, 4.6%sy, 0.0%ni, 16.0%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 8178884k total, 8129980k used, 48904k free, 134904k buffers
Swap: 10490436k total, 148k used, 10490288k free, 6129728k cached

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
7312 root 6 -10 1149m 921m 559m R 97 11.5 107947:09 vmware-vmx
6995 root 6 -10 779m 687m 317m R 92 8.6 107374:31 vmware-vmx
6693 root 6 -10 880m 659m 409m S 85 8.3 76947:33 vmware-vmx
12937 root 6 -10 960m 719m 523m S 75 9.0 67219:49 vmware-vmx
```

In bold are the cpu usage for my 4 virtuals guests

These guests are running on a linux system, and the appropriate process are usually 5% -> 15% of cpu

I don't understang why , since a few days I have this big problem.

This is the "top" on a virtual guest which is at 95% of cpu load

```
top - 11:23:15 up 194 days, 23:13, 4 users, load average: 0.25, 0.47, 0.59
Tasks: 92 total, 2 running, 90 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 1.4%us, 7.7%sy, 0.0%ni, 90.5%id, 0.5%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 382296k total, 369732k used, 12564k free, 145156k buffers
Swap: 979924k total, 13956k used, 965968k free, 86988k cached

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
3691 root 20 0 23948 1148 960 S 13.0 0.3 15339:23 vmware-guestd
3840 root 20 0 19880 584 512 S 7.7 0.2 1729:17 hald-addon-stor
```

This virtual guest state is ok ...

If anyone has any ideas ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

vmware server under linux ... well - have some problems especially with disk i/o.

few things you can do to get things better are described [here](http://www.stress-free.co.nz/vmware_server_20_optimisations) and [there](http://blog.lodeblomme.be/2008/10/24/vmware-server-disk-io-performance/). also [this](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/167897) thread is interesting.

if you can - go [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/).